# Nested Angular Subscriptions not Firing

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have 3 subscriptions I need to subscribe to. But when I run it, only 1 or 2 of them fire out of 3. I even tried swapping the order of the subscriptions and the last one still doesn't get fired. I also tried running these in the `constructor` of my angular component and in `ngOnInit()`. I get the same response.

**Attempt 1:**

```
this.n.authorizations.subscribe(x => {
    alert("1"); // ✅
    this.n.pages.subscribe(y => {
        alert("2"); // ❌
        this.n.user.subscribe(user => {
            alert("3"); // ❌
        });
    });
});
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
this.n.pages.subscribe(y => {
    alert("1"); // ✅
    this.n.authorizations.subscribe(x => {
        alert("2"); // ✅
        this.n.user.subscribe(user => {
            alert("3"); // ❌
        });
    });
});
```

**Attempt 3:**

```
this.n.user.subscribe(user => {
    alert("1"); // ✅
    this.n.authorizations.subscribe(x => {
        alert("2"); // ✅
        this.n.pages.subscribe(y => {
            alert("3"); // ❌
        });
    });
});
```

I do have the code for these services, but they're long and complicated. Probably not related to the problem.

Comment: Do you need to do something after each subscription, or just at the end?

Comment: @user184994 sorry. I just need to do something at the end.

Comment: I would use pipe instead of subscribe, you can chain them all together like that

Comment: May be during execution of subscription there some exception is raised? - console show something?

Comment: Looks like your async call for `pages` is already completed before you subscribe to it.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the approaches you're following, looks like any subscription doesn't depend on the other subscriptions.

So in that case, why not **[`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)** them and then `subscribe` to the joined Observable.

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
...
const combined = forkJoin(
  this.n.user,
  this.n.authorizations,
  this.n.pages
);
...
combined.subscribe(
  [user, auths, pages] => console.log(user, auths, pages),
  error => console.log(error),
  () => console.log('Combined Completed')
);
```

Comment: Thanks. I just tried it but it never fired: https://i.imgur.com/z2KKk5P.png

Comment: @AskYous, do these Observables make any calls to any APIs? If yes, can you please check if the API calls are being made in the network tab of your Dev Tools?  If no, then can you please check if they're being fired when used individually?

Comment: One of them is probably throwing an error which will terminate the observable chain.  Try adding combined.subscribe(()=> {}, (error) => {console.log(error);}, ()=> { console.log('onComplete') } )

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem (kind of). On the first attempt, the subscription to `pages` occured after the `pages` observable resolved. So I changed the return object in that service function to a `ReplaySubject` instead of a `Subject`, which causes late subscribers to get the most recent value emitted. I don't know how all this happened but this resolved my problem. It doesn't make sense though.

Edit: As another user suggested, BehaviorSubject would be better in this case.

Comment: If you only need the last value then BehaviorSubject is the way to go. When I first started I didn't know about these, only Subject. 
 Almost always I find now if i'm setting up a Subject that I use BehaviorSubject. 
 Since for that use case you almost always want the most recent value no matter when you subscribe.  More info -> https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-rxjs-behaviorsubject-replaysubject-and-asyncsubject-8cc061f1cfc0

Comment: If your subscriptions are independent, the approach suggested by @SiddAjmera seems the right one. More generally speacking, nested subscription are usually a code smell. RxJS encourages you to use pipe to combine operators and subscribe only once at the end. Also the use of Subject and its subclasses is often an indication of a reactive design not so lean.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are chaining things that shouldn't be chained.

```
this.n.user.subscribe(user => {
    alert("1");
});
this.n.authorizations.subscribe(x => {
    alert("2");
});
this.n.pages.subscribe(y => {
    alert("3");
});
```

When you subscribe like you have, your inner subscriptions *aren't even attached* until your outer subscriptions receive their first value.